# Tortoise SVN: how to svn update folder but NOT its subfolders?

Tags: svn, file, tortoisesvn, subdirectory

This is probably something that has got a simple solution, but I'm probably not good at all in using Tortoise SVN.

I have this working direcetory that I checked out some time ago:

```
/folder
   file1
   file2
   /subfolder1
   /subfolder2
```

Now all I want to do is to **SVN UPDATE my working directory only for the files in `/folder`, but NOT its subfolders**. How do I do this?

Be aware that **on the SVN server repository, `/folder` now contains new files `file3`, `file4`** that I want to see in the working directory after the SVN UPDATE.

**EDIT** since maybe it's not clear: subfolders MUST not be touched by SVN during SVN UPDATE, I don't want it to touch them at all. I tried to use *Greg* answer but it does not work and **WARNING: subfolder1 and subfolder2 will get DELETED** from your working copy during the update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I normally perform partial updates from the "Check for modifications" dialogue. I launch it, I click on "Check repository" to get available updates and then right click on the exact items I want to fetch.

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm! This is the perfect answer! I'm clueless why people keep upvoting Greg answer that is nice for how it details, but it's wrong.

Answer (score 27):

You can make SVN update non-recursively by using this command:

```
svn update --depth=files
```

The `--depth` argument can take the following parameters: `empty`, `files`, `immediates` or `infinity`

To do this using the GUI rather than command line, you can use `Update to revision`, which can be found here:

[image]

and then chosing the `Head` revision, you can specify how recursive the update is:
[image]

In your case, choosing  `Immediate children, including folders` will be most appropriate.

Comment: I tried this, before asking this question, but it diod not work, It was deleting subfolders, don't know why. I'm trying again, I'll let you know.

Comment: if you want to bring the subfolders too, choose "immediate children, including folders"

Comment: Juts tried again, I choose "Only file children", files are update and new files on SVN servers are checked out too, but the problem is that all subfolders in working copy are deleted!

Comment: @Greg: if I choose Immediate children, including folder" the issue simply comes up again but this time in files contained in the subfolders, these ones are deleted during the update. I don't know it this is the way to go. I don't need to update subfolder, I want SVN to NOT otuch subdfolder at all, I will update them in future, I want him to UPDATE only the main folder and all its files without touching/deleting the subfolders.

Comment: can you try the command line update command with the `immediates` and `empty` attributes, let us know what effect they have?

Comment: @Greg: I'm using Tortoise cause I have no idea of where to go for command line, svn.exe is not even in the WINDOWS PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Update`, use TortoiseSVN's `Update to Revision`. Specify `HEAD` as the revision to update to (or whatever revision you want to update to), and then check off the box that says "Only update the top folder."

Greg's solution works fine if you issue an SVN command via TortoiseSVN or you're using a command line SVN client.

Comment: There is no such an option called "Only update the top folder" Myabe you meant "Only this item". I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.6.10 Build 19898 what's yout version?